# How to set a compound primary key using a varchar field and an int auto increment field?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Using mariadb, I want to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`producttype` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`code` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`price` double default 0.0,
`stock` int default 0,
PRIMARY KEY(`producttype`, `code`)
```

So the id of a product, for example a TV, could be: TV001.

This gives the next error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

If you really want the id of a product to be formed by the type plus a auto incremental integer, how would you do this?

Thank you

Comment: See `INT(3) ZEROFILL`.

Comment: Or, for only 3 digits, `SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight change to your definition: (the added `key` portion, to satisfy the error's `...one auto column and it must be defined as a key` message)

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`producttype` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`code` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`price` double default 0.0,
`stock` int default 0,
key (`code`),
PRIMARY KEY(`producttype`, `code`));
```

...worked for me:

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE `products` (
    -> `producttype` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    -> `code` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    -> `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    -> `price` double default 0.0,
    -> `stock` int default 0,
    -> key (`code`),
    -> PRIMARY KEY(`producttype`, `code`));

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)
```

...then checking the table afterwards:

```
MariaDB [test]> desc products;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| producttype | varchar(15)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| code        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | double       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| stock       | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Although valid, it is probably not what the OP wanted.  InnoDB does not have the feature of starting over the ids (`code` in this case) with each different `producttype`.  That is "1" will be unique to TV001; "1" other types will use unique ids.

Comment: @RickJames: I can see that point. I was thinking that the pattern would be more like `TV001`, `TV002`, `PK003`, `DT004`, etc. I had not considered a start-over aspect within a specific `producttype`, but that the `producttype`+`code` would simply use the next `code` value.